# Users to register only lower case letters

Tags: php, uppercase, lowercase

I have this register page , and i would like to have the script register only lower case letters : pretty 
I do not want it to register :Pretty , PRETTy , PRETTY ...
Here is the code , what do i need to add , or do i change something in the DB ?

Thanks so much for the help !

```
public function addField($field_name){

    if (!array_key_exists($field_name, $this->fields))
    {
        if ($field_name=='username') {
            $field = new field_join_username();
            parent::registerField($field);
        }

        if ($field_name=='email') {
            $field = new field_join_email();
            parent::registerField($field);
        }
    }

    parent::addField($field_name);
}
```

Comment: The code is not related to what you are trying to do. No usernames mentioned.

Comment: That code has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 4):

You can use `strtolower` on the input to convert it to lowercase.

Comment: Just remember to tell the user that it will be all converted to lowercase

Comment: I know , but this is the Join for , so i do not know where to add the strtolower ... and how ..

Comment: </td>
        {else}
         <td class="label">
            {label %.profile_fields.label_join.`$field.id` for=$field.name}{if $field.required}*{/if}
         </td>
         <td class="value">{input name=$field.name labelsection=profile_fields.value}</td>
        {/if}
        
       </tr>
       {if $field.confirm}
        <tr>
         <td class="label">
            {label %.profile_fields.confirm.`$field.id` for="re_`$field.name`"}{if $field.required}*{/if}
         </td>
         <td class="value">{input name="re_`$field.name`"

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what this code is part of, but it should be a simple matter of calling strtolower() on the user's input.

Comment: Hi , here is the more detailed code : <td class="label">
            {label %.profile_fields.label_join.`$field.id` for=$field.name}{if $field.required}*{/if}
         </td>
         <td class="value">{input name=$field.name labelsection=profile_fields.value}</td>
        {/if}
        
       </tr>
       {if $field.confirm}
        <tr>
         <td class="label">
            {label %.profile_fields.confirm.`$field.id` for="re_`$field.name`"}{if $field.required}*{/if}
         </td>
         <td class="value">{input name="re_`$field.name`" labelsection=profile_fields.value}</td>

Comment: Err...that's...not...PHP. Is that Smarty?

Answer (score 0):

u can use regular expression for username in both javascript and php
 pattern would be

#### javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var regex = /^[a-z]$/;
var userinput = jQuery('#username').val();
 if (regex.test(userinput )) {
  alert("VALID username");
 } else {
  alert("INVALID username");
 }
}
</script>
```

#### php

```
$pattern = '/^[a-z]$/';
preg_match($pattern, $userinput, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```