# Case sensitive , add strtolower

Tags: php, case-sensitive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Users to register only lower case letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102938/users-to-register-only-lower-case-letters)

Hi, I have this register page , and i would like to have the script register only lower case letters : pretty 
I do not want it to register :`Pretty , PRETTy , PRETTY ...` Here is the code , what do i need to add to it ?

```
public function addField($field_name){

    if (!array_key_exists($field_name, $this->fields))
    {
        if ($field_name=='username') {
            $field = new field_join_username();
            parent::registerField($field);
        }

        if ($field_name=='email') {
            $field = new field_join_email();
            parent::registerField($field);
        }
    }

    parent::addField($field_name);
}
```

Comment: Why not look at the answers given to your previous question [Users to register only lower case letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102938/users-to-register-only-lower-case-letters) rather than just asking it again

Comment: strtolower($fieldname), as you mentioned in title, doesn't work for you?

Comment: Just turn `$field_name`’s value into lowercase before using it: `$field_name = strtolower($field_name);`.

Answer (score 0):

Where's that code taken from? Are you trying to change existing code?

As far as I can see, this only adds fields not *values* of fields where the `strtolower` should be applied, so applying strtolower to field_name won't do the trick ... but it's hard to guess where to place strtolower without seeing the correct code snippet.